# repmat with interlace or Kronecker product in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Suppose I have a tensor:

```
A=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

Which is a matrix with 2 rows and 3 columns.

I would like to replicate it, suppose twice, to get the following tensor:

```
A2 = [[1,2,3],
      [1,2,3],
      [4,5,6],
      [4,5,6]]
```

Using `tf.repmat` will clearly replicate it differently, so I tried the following code (which works):

```
A_tiled = tf.reshape(tf.tile(A, [1, 2]), [4, 3])
```

Unfortunately, it seems to be working very slow when the number of columns become large. Executing it in Matlab using Kronecker product with a vector of ones (Matlab's "kron") seems to be much faster.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Unfortunately that's a performance implementation issue. We might have to define an operator for that. Could you try with XLA? Are you running on GPU? If you're ready to do some extensive benchmarking, it would be useful: please file an issue at the tensorflow github issue page.

Comment: I will try with XLA... I wasn't aware of it. I tried with on both CPU and GPU and it is isn't as good as I expected. I will look into it more deeply. Thanks.